# error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file

Tags: linux, libstdc++

I Compiled sample C++ Code using ARM CrossCompiler and generated  A.out file in  Linux PC.
And transfered the A.out file file to ZedBoard. When I try to run the A.out file  in Zedboard ,It is  showing the following error,

error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file

Can anyone tell me the solution for the error?

Comment: Make sure `libstdc++.so.6` file exists on your ZedBoard? Or try linking statically if there aren't specific requirements for a dynamic executable.

Answer (score 0):

Install g++ to solve this issue.

Open a terminal and install the g++ package:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```