# dmd error: error while loading shared libraries in Ubuntu Linux 12.04.4 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, d, dmd

I have a new installation of dmd on Ubuntu Server 12.04.4 LTS x64. When I try to compile a simple "Hello, world!" program, I get the following error:

```
dmd: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Well... I'll just say it... I have no idea what that means, so what is it and how do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482184/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libstdc-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not.

I might try to strip everything out and re-do it soon.

Comment: @AaronMcRuer You could use `strace` or `ltrace` to find out where your program trys to find this library. Also you could try to search the error message for more relevant information.